# word frequency counter in r

Tags: r, frequency, cpu-word, text-analysis

I would like to perform a certain operation which will transform the data in the provided format:

### Input :

```
Col_A                         Col_B
textA textB                     10
textB textC                     20
textC textD                     30
textD textE                     40
textE textF                     20
```

### Operation:

```
ColA           ColB(Frequency)            ColC
textA                  1                    10
textB                  2                  10+20
textC                  2                  20+30
textD                  2                  30+40
textE                  2                  40+20
textF                  1                    20
```

### Output:

```
  ColA           ColB(Frequency)            ColC
    textA                  1                  10
    textB                  2                  30
    textC                  2                  50
    textD                  2                  70
    textE                  2                  60
    textF                  1                  20
```

Currently I am using

```
k <- (dfm(A2$Query, ngrams = 1, concatenator = " ", verbose = FALSE))
k <- colSums(k)
k <- as.data.frame(k)
```

And this has given me frequency column. How to achieve colC ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `cSplit()` from the `splitstackshape` package in combination with `dplyr`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
cSplit(df, "Col_A", sep = " ", direction = "long") %>% 
  group_by(Col_A) %>%
  summarise(Freq = n(), ColC = sum(Col_B))
#   Col_A  Freq  ColC
#  (fctr) (int) (int)
#1  textA     1    10
#2  textB     2    30
#3  textC     2    50
#4  textD     2    70
#5  textE     2    60
#6  textF     1    20
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Col_A = structure(1:5, .Label = c("textA textB", 
"textB textC", "textC textD", "textD textE", "textE textF"), class = "factor"), 
    Col_B = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 20L)), .Names = c("Col_A", 
"Col_B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks it does the trick however the method is stuck while doing the same on large data set.

Comment: what do you mean "stuck" ?

Comment: Can you elaborate how does it works ? I am new to R.

Comment: `?cSplit` splits the values in `Col_A` by the `" "` delimiter and stacks the data in the `long` format. Check the output before the first `%>%`, now this output is summarised by the subsequent `dplyr` calls.

Comment: Hi,
If suppose instead of unigram i want to do the same thing with bigram then how will i proceed ?

Doing bi-gram will return input as the output in this case. If you want i can modify the question along with some more data. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `separate/gather`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, Col_A, into = c("Col_A1", "Col_A2")) %>%
         gather(Var, ColA, -Col_B) %>%
         group_by(ColA) %>%
         summarise(Freq=n(),Col_C= sum(Col_B))
#   ColA  Freq Col_C
#  (chr) (int) (int)
#1 textA     1    10
#2 textB     2    30
#3 textC     2    50
#4 textD     2    70
#5 textE     2    60
#6 textF     1    20
```

---

Or with `base R` options by splitting the 'Col_A' by space, replicate the 'Col_B' by the `lengths` of the `list` output from 'lst' to create a `data.frame` and then use `aggregate` to get the `length` and `sum` of 'Col_B'.

```
lst <- strsplit(df1$Col_A, " ")
d1 <- data.frame(Col_A= unlist(lst), Col_C=rep(df1$Col_B, lengths(lst)))
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(.~Col_A, d1, function(x) c(length(x), sum(x))))
```